# Replace gives different outcomes based on length of string

Tags: excel, vba

I use the following code to convert values entered in US format (0.8) to a propper format (0,8).

`For row = 2 To rowg
    For col = 7 To 8
        If InStr(wsg.Cells(row, col), ".") > 0 Then
            wsg.Cells(row, col).Value = Replace(wsg.Cells(row, col), ".", ",")
        End If
    Next col
Next row`

This usually works well, except for the case that there are 4 decimal places. In the case of 19.1991 it gets converted to 191991, instead of 19,1991. Whilst this is done the format of the cell also changes automatically to the numberformat, instead of the text format I set in my code. For values with 1 or 2 decimal places this doesn't happen.

Comment: Perhaps use `wsg.Cells(row, col).Value = CDbl(Replace(wsg.Cells(row, col), ".", ","))`

Comment: How about using `NUMBERVALUE(A1,",")`

Comment: Try `Format(Replace(wsg.Cells(row, col), ".", ","),"#,##0")`

Comment: A better term may have been regional format, not proper format, who says the US format isn't proper?...

Comment: @Rory That solved it, want to add it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CDbl` to coerce the string returned by `Replace` to a `Double` using regional settings rather than US defaults for VBA:

```
wsg.Cells(row, col).Value = CDbl(Replace(wsg.Cells(row, col), ".", ","))
```

Answer (score 0):

add single quote '

```
For Row = 2 To rowg
    For col = 7 To 8
        If InStr(wsg.Cells(Row, col), ".") > 0 Then
            wsg.Cells(Row, col).Value = "'" & (Replace(wsg.Cells(Row, col), ".", ","))
        End If
    Next col
Next Row
```

Or

```
For Row = 2 To rowg
    For col = 7 To 8
        If InStr(wsg.Cells(Row, col), ".") > 0 Then
            wsg.Cells(Row, col).NumberFormatLocal = "@"
            wsg.Cells(Row, col).Value = (Replace(wsg.Cells(Row, col), ".", ","))
        End If
    Next col
Next Row
```

Comment: This works well when displaying a value. However when I want to use the cell value in other applications (importing the excel) this will cause trouble.